# If ac gives rotten egg smell, does that mean there is an animal in the system?

Tags: hvac

I have just read that if you’d ac is giving a rotten egg smell, it’s probably because an animal has climbed in and died in the vents.

Is it true and if so, I guess just spraying with lycos isn’t enough, one must actually open the vents and physically remove animal?

Can you remove vent covers from outside or are you going to have to remove dashboard etc?

Comment: Means the system needs proper cleaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stinky AC is usually caused by mold buildup on the evaporator coil. Smells like sweaty gym socks. Some people say to spray Lysol into the HVAC system. That won't last. You really have to treat the source of the problem. Purchase a can of KOOL-IT and follow the directions. It injects through the AC drain tube and foams up the entire evaporator coil, killing the mold and treating the coil. It last for about a year and is the same stuff dealers use. See [this post](http://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/ac-smells-musty/) for more details on what causes the problem and how to fix it.

Comment: Good andwer, note that the OP has already been told the same : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/69569/10976

Comment: @SolarMike this is a different question though may have the same answer.

Comment: @JamesWilson you will have noted I made a comment to the **answer**, not your question... which rather questions the point of your comment...